# Autohotkey: Ctrl + 1 mapping

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap mouse click to a button depend on a state of Numlock. If Numlock is 'ON' then I want the normal behavior else map to mouse click. The script I created below works fine but I have trouble remapping <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will result in '!' so it is simple to do but I don't know what's the behavior for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is. The current script has the dummy "Send, {^1}" but that is not the real behavior.

I appreciate any suggestion.

*The Keywait is for simulating holding the mouse button and the script is enable/disabled base on Numlock state.

```
$1::
    if GetKeyState("NumLock","T")
        Send, {1}
    else
    {
        Click down,
        KeyWait 1  
        Click up        
    }
Return

$+1::
    if GetKeyState("NumLock","T")
        Send, {!}
    else
    {
        Click down,
        KeyWait 1  
        Click up        
    }
Return

$^1::
    if GetKeyState("NumLock","T")
        Send, {^1}
    else
    {
        Click down,
        KeyWait 1  
        Click up        
    }
Return
```

Comment: Just do `Send, ^1`

Comment: Oh i forgot ^ is not the key name for {Ctrl}. I added {} just to be consistent with other code format. 

Changed to Send, ^{1} and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you've described, with some cleanup to the code itself. I also recommend reading up on the various Send modes, as `SendInput` is superior in just about every way possible.

```
$1::
    if GetKeyState("NumLock","T")
        SendInput, 1
    else
    {
        Click down
        KeyWait 1
        Click up
    }
Return

$+1::
    if GetKeyState("NumLock","T")
        SendInput, {!}
    else
    {
        Click down
        KeyWait 1
        Click up
    }
Return

$^1::
    if GetKeyState("NumLock","T")
        SendInput, ^1
    else
    {
        Click down
        KeyWait 1
        Click up
    }
Return
```